# Get the index of recently selected option in multiselect dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select dropdown in my html page. How can I get the index of the most recently selected option, not the last. I saw that we can use `'last'`, but it will give the last option which was selected not the most recent.

HTML

```
<select class="carMenu" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carMenu').change(function(){
         console.log($('option:selected',$(this)).index());
    });
});
```

If we select 'Opel' and then 'Volvo', we should get zero as the index. But now it gives index of 'Opel'.

Comment: The web page, by itself, doesn't retain a "memory" of old form input values. You'd have to store every selection in a variable as they happen using `.change()`. You could even attach this selection history to the element itself by using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I tried your code with jquery-2.2.0.min.js on Chrome 48 and I see the correct index. I'm not sure if I understand the question?

Comment: A better explanation of higher level problem you are trying to solve would help

Comment: Please note that a user can select more than one `<option>` at a time in a multiple select so a `change` may reflect numerous differences from prior `change`

Comment: what do you mean by recently? you mean clicked option?

Comment: @Mahdi Ghandhi yes, i mean the clicked option

Comment: @user2190981 would you mind check my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time, I get `carMenu` value, containing the value of all selected options, then I compare it with the last time to detect which item is added recently. Code also supports deselecting options. In fact it keeps a stack of `indexes` and pops `index` on deselect. Try the code :

```
var recent_options = selected_options = added_options = removed_options = [];
var current_values, index;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carMenu').change(function(){
        current_values = $(this).val();
        if (current_values && current_values.length > 0) {
            added_options = current_values.filter(function(x) { return recent_options.indexOf(x) < 0 });
            if (added_options.length > 0) {
                selected_options.push($(this).find("option[value='" + added_options[0] + "']").index());
                console.log("last selected option is : " + selected_options[selected_options.length-1]);
            }
            else {
                removed_options = recent_options.filter(function(x) { return current_values.indexOf(x) < 0 });
                if (removed_options.length > 0) {   
                    index = selected_options.indexOf($(this).find("option[value='" + removed_options[0] + "']").index());
                    if (index > -1)
                        selected_options.splice(index, 1);
                    console.log("last selected option is : " + selected_options[selected_options.length-1]);
                }
            }
        }
        recent_options = current_values ? current_values : [];
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="carMenu" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If you don't want support of deselecting options, simply remove `else` part of `if (added_options.length > 0)`.

Also be aware of *[`indexOf` browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Array.prototype.indexOf)*.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m3hranTi/uzc9jzps/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the `.change()` event, use `.click()` on the option.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.carMenu option').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
      console.log($(this).index());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="carMenu" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: surprised you don't know that `click` on option not supported cross browser. For sure is useless in IE and I think also Safari. Also seems like OP wants to know what changed from previous selections